# How to make a simple Mod_Rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have problems with my shared hosting account. the apache server i'm using scrambles utf8 so i can't use Hebrew/Arabic in the url such as www.mydomain.com/אבא.php

So i want to know how can i make it that if someone asks for the page:
**www.mydomain.com/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%90.php**

he would get to the page: www.mydomain.com/**D790D791D790.php** (without the percentages)
but his browser url will show the first page he asked for (with no redirection).

I guess using mod_rewrite in .htaccess but have no clue how to approach this.
Please help you guys, this is a 911 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about this for a little while now, and unless you know how many sets there are (6 in your example) I don't think there will be a terribly elegant way to do this.  One solution may be to use a rather vague rewrite `RewriteRule ^(.*?%.*?)\.php$ foo.php?bar=$1` then process the data in PHP where you have a few more options and quite a bit more flexibility.

Details of the Regex:

```
^.*?%.*?\.php$

Options: case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “%” literally «%»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the characters “php” literally «php»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Unkwntech there isn't a way to simply match % ? and replace it with nothing or even with a +  or a dash?

Comment: @Tom as far as I'm aware there one cannot do replacements in the mod_rewrite, if this regex doesn't work for you, test it by replacing the ^ with .*? and $ with .*$